# From green to red depending on the value

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need a function that returns a color from red (value 0) to green (value 100) in vb.net. Also I need a way to discover if the color of the font should be white or black, depending on the background color.

Comment: You know the drill, show us what you've done so far. This ain't a code factory. With that being said, what you're looking for is something like the `XNA` [Color.Lerp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.color.lerp(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Linearly interpolation**

I once had the same need to do `linearly interpolation` between two colors in a winform. I will do an exception and share the code behind this as I think it might be useful for not only the OP but others.

The function accept a `Single` value in the range `0.0` *(0%)* to `1.0` *(100%)*.

```
Public Shared Function Lerp(ByVal color1 As Color, ByVal color2 As Color, ByVal amount As Single) As Color
    Const bitmask As Single = 65536.0!
    Dim n As UInteger = CUInt(Math.Round(CDbl(Math.Max(Math.Min((amount * bitmask), bitmask), 0.0!))))
    Dim r As Integer = (CInt(color1.R) + (((CInt(color2.R) - CInt(color1.R)) * CInt(n)) >> 16))
    Dim g As Integer = (CInt(color1.G) + (((CInt(color2.G) - CInt(color1.G)) * CInt(n)) >> 16))
    Dim b As Integer = (CInt(color1.B) + (((CInt(color2.B) - CInt(color1.B)) * CInt(n)) >> 16))
    Dim a As Integer = (CInt(color1.A) + (((CInt(color2.A) - CInt(color1.A)) * CInt(n)) >> 16))
    Return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b)
End Function
```

So in your case it will look like this:

```
Dim value As Integer = 'A value in the range 0 - 100
Dim newColor As Color = Lerp(Color.Red, Color.Green, If((value > 0I), (Math.Min(Math.Max(CSng(value), 0.0!), 100.0!) / 100.0!), 0.0!))
```

**Luminosity**

Regarding the part *"white or black, depending on the background"* you need to know the luminosity of the color. The following function returns 0 for a black and 240 for a white color. So if the luminosity of a given backcolor is `<= 120` one should use a white forecolor.

```
Public Shared Function GetLuminosity(c As Color) As Integer
    Return CInt((((Math.Max(Math.Max(CInt(c.R), CInt(c.G)), CInt(c.B)) + Math.Min(Math.Min(CInt(c.R), CInt(c.G)), CInt(c.B))) * 240) + 255) / 510I)   
End Function
```

Comment: Another way, sure worse than this one, is to use `Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush`, transform it to bitmap and use method `GetPixel`. Knowing this function here, it is an absurd using this way...