# Finding the ratio in an rgb value

Tags: vb.net, math, colors, rgb

I am fairly new to coding (started early this year) and I'm making a program in VB 2010 express that makes a line chart for values that have been given by the user.

In other words, I ask for values and make the program create rectangles on a canvas, one rectangle for every item added to my `ArrayList`.

This part of the code works, now I want a gradient color scheme, so another color for every rectangle. To achieve this I tried this:

```
Dim red As Integer = 254
Dim green As Integer = 141
Dim blue As Integer = 150

calcColor(red, green, blue)
Dim MyBrushColor As Color = Color.FromRgb(red, green, blue)

Private Sub calcColor(ByVal red As Integer, ByVal green As Integer, ByVal blue As Integer)

    If (red <= 0 Or green <= 0 Or blue <= 0) Then
        red = 254
        green = 141
        blue = 150
        red = red + 8
        green = green + 8
        blue = blue + 8
    End If
    If (red >= 254 Or green >= 141 Or blue >= 150) Then
        red = 254
        green = 141
        blue = 150
        red = red - 8
        green = green - 8
        blue = blue - 8
    End If
End Sub
```

Just doing -8 and +8 every time is not going to cut it and once they reach either zero or their inital value they'll have another ratio..

As a very inexperienced coder I have no idea how to calculate this ratio. I just know that it's this kind of code I want.

Comment: If you use the [HSL colour representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space), you should be able to get a nice effect by keeping S (saturation) and L (lightness) constant while varying H (hue). You will need to write functions to convert between RGB and HSL.

Comment: This is probably what I'm looking for, now I just need to try and implemlent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please only look at this if you get stuck.** You will learn more by trying it yourself first. Your teacher has probably seen this.

If you use the [HSL colour representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space), you should be able to get a nice effect by keeping S (saturation) and L (lightness) constant while varying H (hue). You will need to write functions to convert between RGB and HSL - there are many instances of that on the Internet, so here's another one:

```
Public Class ColourRepresentation

    ' Adapted from http://www.geekymonkey.com/Programming/CSharp/RGB2HSL_HSL2RGB.htm
    ' with conversion from C# to VB.NET by http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

    Public Class HSLcolour
        Property H As Double
        Property S As Double
        Property L As Double

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("H={0}, S={1}, L={2}", H, S, L)
        End Function

    End Class

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Convert from HSL to RGB.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="c">An HSLcolour</param>
    ''' <returns>A System.Drawing.Color with A set to 255.</returns>
    ''' <remarks>H, S, L in the range [0.0, 1.0].</remarks>
    Public Shared Function HSLtoRGB(c As HSLcolour) As Color

        Dim r As Double = c.L
        Dim g As Double = c.L
        Dim b As Double = c.L

        Dim v As Double = If((c.L <= 0.5), (c.L * (1.0 + c.S)), (c.L + c.S - c.L * c.S))

        If v > 0 Then
            Dim m As Double = c.L + c.L - v
            Dim sv As Double = (v - m) / v
            c.H *= 6.0
            Dim sextant As Integer = CInt(Math.Truncate(c.H))
            Dim fract As Double = c.H - sextant
            Dim vsf As Double = v * sv * fract
            Dim mid1 As Double = m + vsf
            Dim mid2 As Double = v - vsf

            Select Case sextant
                Case 0, 6
                    r = v
                    g = mid1
                    b = m
                Case 1
                    r = mid2
                    g = v
                    b = m
                Case 2
                    r = m
                    g = v
                    b = mid1
                Case 3
                    r = m
                    g = mid2
                    b = v
                Case 4
                    r = mid1
                    g = m
                    b = v
                Case 5
                    r = v
                    g = m
                    b = mid2
            End Select
        End If

        Return Color.FromArgb(255, CByte(r * 255), CByte(g * 255), CByte(b * 255))

    End Function

    ' Given a Color (RGB Struct) in range of 0-255
    ' Return H,S,L in range of 0-1
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Convert from a Color to an HSLcolour.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="rgb">A System.Drawing.Color.</param>
    ''' <returns>An HSLcolour.</returns>
    ''' <remarks>Ignores Alpha value in the parameter.</remarks>
    Public Shared Function RGBtoHSL(rgb As Color) As HSLcolour
        Dim r As Double = rgb.R / 255.0
        Dim g As Double = rgb.G / 255.0
        Dim b As Double = rgb.B / 255.0

        Dim v As Double = Math.Max(r, g)
        v = Math.Max(v, b)
        Dim m As Double = Math.Min(r, g)
        m = Math.Min(m, b)
        Dim l As Double = (m + v) / 2.0

        If l <= 0.0 Then
            Return New HSLcolour With {.H = 0, .L = 0, .S = 0}
        End If

        Dim vm As Double = v - m
        Dim s As Double = vm

        If s > 0.0 Then
            s /= If((l <= 0.5), (v + m), (2.0 - v - m))
        Else
            Return New HSLcolour With {.H = 0, .L = 0, .S = 0}
        End If

        Dim r2 As Double = (v - r) / vm
        Dim g2 As Double = (v - g) / vm
        Dim b2 As Double = (v - b) / vm

        Dim h As Double = 0
        If r = v Then
            h = (If(g = m, 5.0 + b2, 1.0 - g2))
        ElseIf g = v Then
            h = (If(b = m, 1.0 + r2, 3.0 - b2))
        Else
            h = (If(r = m, 3.0 + g2, 5.0 - r2))
        End If

        h /= 6.0

        Return New HSLcolour With {.H = h, .L = l, .S = s}

    End Function

End Class
```

Then you will need a way of varying the hue, which I have used in this crude example of drawing a bar chart (I put one PictureBox on a Form):

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer On

Public Class Form1

    Dim rand As New Random
    Dim data As List(Of Double)

    Private Function DoubleModOne(value As Double) As Double
        While value > 1.0
            value -= 1.0
        End While
        While value < 0.0
            value += 1.0
        End While

        Return value

    End Function

    Sub DrawBars(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim target = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)

        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.DarkGray)

        ' an approximation of the bar width
        'TODO: Improve the approximation.
        Dim barWidth As Integer = CInt(CDbl(target.Width) / data.Count)
        Dim maxBarHeight = target.Height

        Using br As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
            Dim r As Rectangle

            'TODO: make it work for Color.Gainsboro
            Dim startColour = ColourRepresentation.RGBtoHSL(Color.Fuchsia)
            ' these components are broken out in case something needs to be done to them.
            Dim startColourH = startColour.H
            Dim startColourS = startColour.S
            Dim startColourL = startColour.L
            ' Using 1.0 as the quotient makes the colours go through the whole spectrum.
            Dim colourInc As Double = 1.0 / data.Count

            ' Only expects data to be in the range (0, 1).
            For i = 0 To data.Count - 1
                Dim thisHSLcolour As New ColourRepresentation.HSLcolour With {.H = DoubleModOne(startColourH + i * colourInc), .S = startColourS, .L = startColourL}
                br.Color = ColourRepresentation.HSLtoRGB(thisHSLcolour)
                r = New Rectangle(CInt(i * barWidth), CInt(data(i) * maxBarHeight), barWidth, maxBarHeight)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, r)
            Next

        End Using

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim nBars = 100
        data = New List(Of Double)(nBars)
        For i = 0 To nBars - 1
            data.Add(rand.NextDouble())
        Next

        AddHandler PictureBox1.Paint, AddressOf DrawBars

    End Sub

End Class
```

Resulting in:

[image]

No-one ever accused me of choosing subtle colours, lol.

Comment: As the drawing pen did not help me, this is by far the best I could have done in the exercise and my teacher will be mind blown. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Michiel You're welcome. Do remember to state that you got the RGB<->HSL methods from the Internet.

Comment: I'm still working into implementing this code, I have provided the link to this question as my source. Thank you once again

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel. The GDI+ library provides linear gradient brushes. You define starting point and an end point and colors in between and just use this brush for painting.

Example (will comment below):

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(400, 400)
Using brush As Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush = New Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), _
                                                                                     New Point(400, 400), _
                                                                                     Color.Blue, _
                                                                                     Color.Red)
    Using p As New Pen(brush)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            For i = 1 To 400 Step 10
                g.DrawRectangle(p, i - 5, i - 5, 10, 10)
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
PictureBox1.Image = bmp
```

First I create a bitmap as a canvas (`bmp`).
I then create a new object of the paint class. In the constructor I provide an object of the LinearGradientBrush class, with a start point in the top left corner, and an end point in the lower right with colors blue at the start and red at the end.
I then just paint a row of rectangles along the diagonal with this pen for reference.

[image]

This brush can do much more, as well. It can use several points on planes and so on and does the color interpolation for you. You just draw with it. Refer to the MSDN for further details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientbrush.aspx

Comment: Read up on `Interpolation` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation). You have a starting value and an end value and want to get (linear) interpolated points between them (individual for R, G and B).

Comment: @Michiel Maybe this is what you're looking for?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21624017/1842065

Comment: Interpolation and @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå these definitely helped me understanding this more. Thank you Jens and Bjørn the input!