# Foreground color always takes the white

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a MenuStrip which I associate a class made by me in order to get a different design than the default.

I created this code that allows me to generate a random color and change the foreground of the menu:

```
Dim randNum As Int32 = New Random().Next(0, 13)
Custom_Menu.Switch_Theme(Custom_Menu.Background_Color.Light, Color.FromArgb(randNum))
Form1.MenuStrip1.Invalidate()
```

The menu seems to change color always black, and I do not understand why.
This is the method that allows you to change color, built in my class:

```
Public Shared Sub Switch_Theme(Background As Background_Color, Foreground As Color)
    If Background = Background_Color.Black Then
        BgColor = Color.Black
        ItemColor = Color.White
    Else
        BgColor = Color.White
        ItemColor = Color.Black
    End If
    ItemSelect = Foreground
End Sub
```

The first part will change the background color of the menu, the second to forecolor.
What could be causing this? I would also like to exclude from colors-white, otherwise the text takes on the color of the form and the user can not see what is written on the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "random" ARGB value will always be between 0 and 12. You need to generate a random number for each channel.

```
Static rnd As New Random()

Dim red As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 256)
Dim green As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 256)
Dim blue As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 256)

Custom_Menu.Switch_Theme(Custom_Menu.Background_Color.Light, Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue))
```

Also, you might find my answer in this post useful:

[Linearly interpolation and luminosity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21624017/1842065)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
Dim randNum As Int32 = New Random().Next(0, 13)
Custom_Menu.Switch_Theme(Custom_Menu.Background_Color.Light, Color.FromArgb(randNum))
```

You pass random color values from 0 to 12 to `Color.FromArgb` method. ARGB is 32-bit color space, so your color values are 0x00000000 to 0x0000000C. 0x00000000 is black, 0x0000000C is very very dark blue, so it may look as black too.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space

Comment: One possible fix:

Custom_Menu.Switch_Theme(Custom_Menu.Background_Color.Black, Color.FromArgb(Int(Rnd() * 255), Int(Rnd() * 255), Int(Rnd() * 255)))

but I would like to generate only 13 colors

Comment: Yes. If you want only 13 colors, then write them in an array  (fixed values or randomly generated at startup), then select random value from this array.